# Hydrographic Survey Problem

Tags: fluid-mechanics, homework

I have been trying, but I can't figure out how I should solve this using the area velocity method. It is the only method as our professor taught us.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: `I Have been trying really hard` ... please show your work